# Why is jquery.fileupload-validate raising $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.processQueue.push error?

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I am using [jquery file upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) on a page, and the following error is being raised in the browser console.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.processQueue.push')
```

It appears to be coming from jquery.fileupload-validate.

I have been unable to find much information about this error. From previous experience jquery file upload seems to be very sensitive to the order in which modules are loaded, but again I've been unable to find much in the way of documentation about this.

Has anyone else encountered this error, or can shed some light on load order or other possible causes?

BTW, I am currently loading files in the following order (though have tried others without success)

```
jquery.fileupload
jquery.fileupload-ui
jquery.fileupload-validate
jquery.fileupload-process
jquery.fileupload-image
jquery.iframe-transport
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this order:

```
js/jquery-3.3.1.js
js/jquery.ui.widget.js
js/jquery.iframe-transport.js
js/jquery.fileupload.js
js/jquery.fileupload-process.js
js/jquery.fileupload-image.js
js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js
```